# Count how many times specific element occurs in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
array = [ 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 8]
```

Is there a method that lets you count how many times an item occurs in array that may be similar to:

```
array.include?2
```

I want to count how many times the number 2 occurs in the array.

Comment: Must be a dup? Can't find one though.

Comment: @SagarPandya thats what I was thinking, I spent a lot of time searching but couldnt find anything very relevant. However I have got the perfect answer below from Jagdeep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count) method on `Array` takes arguments too.

```
array = [ 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 8]
array.count(2)
 => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
p array.select {|x| x.eql? 2}.count
```

Another way

```
p array.grep(2).count
```

Another one

```
p array.count {|x| x.eql? 2}
```

Comment: can also be `array.count { |x| x.eql? 2 }`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh AH, yes!

Comment: It makes no difference for integers but `==` is more common than `eql?`,

Comment: @Kris `.eql?` is the ruby style of writing =, When I write `==` it feels like i am writing C!

Comment: In this case `1.eql?(1.0) #=> false` but `1 == 1.0 #=> true`. Just something to be aware of. Also `==` is a method call in the same way as `eql?`, you can do the horrible looking `1.==(1.0)`.

Comment: @Kris Oh thank you, I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: Space your code like Jagdeep e.g. `array.select { |x| x.eql? 2 }.count`.